# Why would a RandomAccessFile fail to open because the file is in use by another process?

Tags: java, windows, file-locking

I've got a Java program that implements a local data store using `RandomAccessFile` and cooperative locking (that is, `RandomAccessFile.getChannel().lock()`). The situation is that there may be several processes of the program accessing the same files, which is why I'm using cooperative locking to synchronize them, but there should never be any process of another program using or locking these files.

My implementation generally works (especially for me using Linux), but every once in a while I get a report from a user where `new RandomAccessFile(path, "rw")` fails on Windows with the Windows-specific "The process can not access the file because this file is used by another process" error.

The error seems to be sporadic, and I haven't been able to find any way to reproduce it whatsoever, let alone reliably, and so therefore I cannot provide a minimal example. Rather, my question is: Under what conditions on Windows *can* this error even occur? Clearly, `RandomAccessFiles` are supposed to be shareable between processes, the locking is supposed to be cooperative, and there *shouldn't* be any other programs using these files that could be using mandatory locks. I don't see how that leaves room for this error to be thrown. I suppose some users could potentially be running some really obscure software that does weird things, but the errors seem to be a bit too common for it to be something extraordinary. Could Antivirus programs possibly be a cause? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Windows filesystems implement shared data access that's enforced when a file is opened (`CreateFileW`), whereas file locking is based on byte ranges and enforced at time of access (`ReadFile` or `WriteFile`). Whenever a file is opened with data access (read/execute, write/append, delete), the open has to specify whether read, write, and delete access can be shared with other opens (regardless of the process, including the current process). If the file is already open with data access, and the desired data access is not shared, the open fails with a sharing violation error (32).

Comment: @ErykSun: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but it sounds like you're saying that opening a file in that manner would deterministically and reliably make it un-openable by other processes, but this is not what I'm observing. I've tried writing a minimal test case that opens a given path as a `RandomAccessFile` (and also locks it for good measure), and I seem to be able to run an arbitrary number of processes of that program on the same file.

Comment: I'm describing what causes a sharing violation to occur. I don't know what Java `RandomAccessFile` shares. It probably shares read and write access, and not delete access. If some other program has already opened the file with delete access, or opened it with any data access without sharing read and/or write access, then your open will fail with a sharing violation error. (Also, again, despite the misleading error message, a sharing violation has nothing to do with processes. You can get a sharing violation with two opens in the same process.)

Comment: @ErykSun: Right. Is that the only possible way to get a sharing violation, though? It's confusing, because it would seem to imply that some other program is holding these files open, and there really shouldn't be any other program interested in these files. As I speculated in the question, could this possibly be an issue with some Antivirus program or somesuch?

Comment: Also, I checked the OpenJDK sources, and unless Oracle's JDK has some unlikely proprietary changes, `new RandomAccessFile(path, "rw")` does indeed call `CreateFileW(path, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)`.

Comment: Trying to access a paging file in an NTFS filesystem fails with a sharing violation, as does trying to get write-data access to a file that's mapped as an executable image (`SEC_IMAGE`). But normally it's just based on a file's share-access record, which tracks the number of times the file is open with read, write, or delete access and the number of times that read, write, and delete access are shared. A filesystem passes this record to [`IoCheckShareAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-iocheckshareaccess).